# Korenix Switch JetNet 4508v2 SSH Problem

Tags: switch, ssh, bug

Does anybody know, or has anybody worked with Korenix JetNet 4508v2? This Switch has a very important Bug in the Firmware. SSH is working fine, but for a period of time. Then, ssh is not working anymore, and unfortunately you dont have direct access to the switch. I am working remotely, and i have to call the Colleague there to restart the Switches.
Can anyone suggest any solution to this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If, as you claim, it is a firmware bug, you need to upgrade the firmware.

Comment: Depending on what the bug is, preemtively restarting the SSH daemon before it stops working may help (but may also introduce new problems), or connecting the device to a serial console server so you have another way to access it may work. But as Ron said, getting a firmware upgrade sounds like the best thing to do.

Comment: @RonMaupin, I have upgraded the latest Firmware, but there is nothing to fix this issue.

Comment: @TeunVink, to connect all the devices to a serial console Server is very difficult, because there are all distributed on different locations. How do you mean to restart the SSH Daemon? I don't know, when it will stop working.

Comment: We cannot solve a firmware bug. If there are several locations, you may need to install several terminal servers.

Comment: I have no idea how you can restart the SSH daemon, I never even heard of this brand of switches. I just suggest what I would try to do on any managed device. If this is the latest sofware version you're on, you should open a support case with the vendor to get these issues fixed.

Comment: @TeunVink, i already contacted with them, in order to find a solution. Yes, I know they are not well-known Company for Network Devices.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments you can't solve an problem inherent in the hardware/firmware if there's no update fixing it. Latest firmware seems to be 1.4a and possibly the 5 year warranty isn't over yet, so you could RMA.

However, you can work around - either

1. replace the faulty device (best)
2. reboot by scheduled script before the problem comes up (only possible when it's predictable)
3. reboot by other means if SSH is dead (telnet, serial, ...)
4. connect the device to a PDU where you can remotely toggle the power; this can also be done automatically by a monitoring script

Comment: Thanks for your Inrormations. The 1 solution is almost impossible to do, because the Company does not pay money for other Devices. The Second solution. i have already thought it, the problem is, as you say, that it is not always predictable. Serial is very difficult also, because all devices are distributed on different Locatons, Telnet is not safe. The 4 solution looks to be the best.
One more question to you. Do you think is it possible to "fix", with a kind of trick, the firmware to bypass the Bug Error?

Comment: @JimPap "telnet is not safe" - no, of course not. You're working around a known fault here, so obviously security is of no concern. If it was you'd dump the faulty switches and replace them (they're EoLed anyway). For fixing the firmware, you'd need to reverse engineer it, find and patch the bug and redeploy. For an excellent hardware hack, that's a 1 to 10 day's job but it may be impossible if the firmware is cryptographically signed (and for normal people anyway). If you haven't got at least 50 of those switches the cost of such a patch likely can't be justified.

Comment: [...] So, "possible?" likely, "reasonable?" no.

Comment: we have around 105-110 Switches for this kind of model. I don't know if the firmware is cryptographically signed. But, I think maybe it is worth doing it, since i don't think the Company will change these Network Devices soon. How do you mean to patch the bug and redeploy it. I don't ever try it before.

Comment: @JimPap First, you need to hire the "excellent hardware hack". Everything else is up to her/him.

Comment: Is it possible via SNMP to restart this device, when SSH is not working.

Comment: It's generally possible with SNMP but you'll need to check for that device. It's also possible that SNMP hangs along with SSH but that you'll need to test as well.

Comment: so you mean, that maybe this Bug error maybe be occurred through SNMP. I think, I have to test the device without SNMP configuration, if it is working with SSH or not. What do you mean?

Comment: No, I mean the same bug could have an impact on SNMP as well, so that workaround might not do.